# How to use find() and find_all() in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently doing some web scraping. I have this HTML:

```
<meta property="og:price:amount" content="1.89"/>
<meta property="og:price:standard_amount" content="6.31"/>
<meta property="og:price:currency" content="USD"/>
```

I'm using beautiful soup (Python).

The information I want to extract is the 1.89 and the 6.31 (prices of product).

This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = requests.get('https://spanish.alibaba.com/product-detail/crazy-hot-selling-multifunctional-battery-powered-360-degree-rotation-led-light-makeup-mirror-60769168637.html?spm=a2700.8270666-66.2016122619262.17.5a4d5d09En8wm9')

# Create a BeautifulSoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
#print(soup.get_text())
# get the repo list


v2 = soup.find_all("meta", {"property": "og:price:amount", "content": True}['content'] )
print("v2 is",v2)
```

The error is in the `.find_all()` function, I'm not sure how to extract the data. I tried the `.find()` function too

This is the information I got of how the beautiful soup function works:
`Signature: find_all(name, attrs, recursive, string, limit, **kwargs)`

Help me configure the  `.find()` function. Thank you!

Comment: It's "scraping," not "scrapping."  Scrapping is what you do to an old car when it will no longer run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `find_all()` just use `find()`

`find_all()` returns list of elements.

```
v2 = soup.find("meta", {"property": "og:price:amount", "content": True})['content'] 
print("v2 is",v2)
```

Or you can use **Css selctor**:

```
v2 = soup.select_one('meta[property="og:price:amount"][content]')['content']
print("v2 is",v2)
```

Answer (score 2):

`.find_all()` will return a list. You need to iterate through that list. Or your other option as suggested is to use `.find()`. `.find()` will return the first element, regardless of how many there are in the html. But seeing you want multiple elements, you'll need to also use regex to find all the ones that contain `'og:price:'`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

page = requests.get('https://spanish.alibaba.com/product-detail/crazy-hot-selling-multifunctional-battery-powered-360-degree-rotation-led-light-makeup-mirror-60769168637.html?spm=a2700.8270666-66.2016122619262.17.5a4d5d09En8wm9')

# Create a BeautifulSoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
#print(soup.get_text())
# get the repo list

regex = re.compile('.*og:price:.*')
v2 = soup.find_all("meta", {"property": regex, "content": True})

for each in v2:
    print('%s is %s' %(each['property'].split(':')[-1], each['content']))
```

**Output:**

```
amount is 1.89
standard_amount is 6.31
currency is USD
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html= '''<meta property="og:price:amount" content="1.89"/>
<meta property="og:price:standard_amount" content="6.31"/>
<meta property="og:price:currency" content="USD"/>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for i in soup.find_all('meta'):
    print(i.get('property')[9:], i.get('content'))
```

OUTPUT

```
amount 1.89
standard_amount 6.31
currency USD
```